# Why is git warning of CRLF on a file flagged as binary?

Tags: git

I've got a file which has been flagged as binary:

```
$ cat .gitattributes
dist/* binary
$ git check-attr -a ./dist/app.js
./dist/app.js: binary: set
./dist/app.js: diff: unset
./dist/app.js: merge: unset
./dist/app.js: text: auto
```

And `git diff` correctly treats the file as binary:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/dist/app.js b/dist/app.js
index 9c05798..fbcedd4 100644
Binary files a/dist/app.js and b/dist/app.js differ
```

But when I run `git status`, I get a warning about `CRLF` conversions:

```
$ git status
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in dist/app.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   dist/app.js
```

What's going on? Why is git warning me about CRLFs in this file?

Answer (score 4):

Git 2.10 (Q3 2016) should be more careful about crlf in binary.

See [commit 6523728](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6523728499e77afaed0008875b19b308682c3f88) (28 Jun 2016) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 21bed62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bed620cd2d4fc4fb3d42447136c9f899ede5bb), 25 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `convert`: unify the "`auto`" handling of CRLF

> Before this change,
>
> ```
> $ echo "* text=auto" >.gitattributes
> $ echo "* eol=crlf" >>.gitattributes
> ```
>
> would have the same effect as
>
> ```
> $ echo "* text" >.gitattributes
> $ git config core.eol crlf
> ```
>
> **Since the '`eol`' attribute had higher priority than '`text=auto`', this may corrupt binary files and is not what most users expect to happen**.
>
> Make the 'eol' attribute to obey 'text=auto' and now
>
> ```
> $ echo "* text=auto" >.gitattributes
> $ echo "* eol=crlf" >>.gitattributes
> ```
>
> behaves the same as
>
> ```
> $ echo "* text=auto" >.gitattributes
> $ git config core.eol crlf
> ```

---

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) makes sure the normalization uses the right commands
See [commit 8599974](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85999743e74e35b9100cbeb94112a8ac39ab5a0e) (12 Apr 2017) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 848d9a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/848d9a9bb7407cd3a2d45941f732b2ddc32588a7), 24 Apr 2017)</sup>

To [trigger a re-normalization](https://github.com/git/git/blob/848d9a9bb7407cd3a2d45941f732b2ddc32588a7/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L228-L239):

> From a clean working directory:
>
> ```
> $ echo "* text=auto" >.gitattributes
> $ rm .git/index     # Remove the index to re-scan the working directory
> $ git add .
> $ git status        # Show files that will be normalized
> $ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
> ```

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), the eol attribute documentation is completed.

See [commit 8c591db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c591dbfcef9b4d40cfae7f675a2c99a0e925157), [commit ab96151](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab961513c4a6bb1d65636829aa962593cfd934e9) (11 Jan 2022) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8db2f66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8db2f665e1b25c2e88ddb00b402a4aa3b73a4cf4), 11 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c591dbfcef9b4d40cfae7f675a2c99a0e925157): correct documentation about eol attribute
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> The documentation for the eol attribute states that it is "effectively setting the text attribute".
>
> However, this implies that it forces the text attribute to always be set, which has not been the case since [6523728](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6523728499e77afaed0008875b19b308682c3f88) (`convert`: unify the , 2016-06-28, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21bed620cd2d4fc4fb3d42447136c9f899ede5bb) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c6d1f9807c67532e7fb545a944b064faff0f70b)) ("convert: unify the "auto" handling of CRLF", 2016-06-28).
>
> Let's avoid confusing users (and the present author when trying to describe Git's behavior to others) by clearly documenting in which cases the "eol" attribute has effect.
>
> Specifically, the attribute always has an effect unless the file is explicitly set as `-text`, or the file is set as `text=auto` and the file is detected as binary.

`gitattributes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c591dbfcef9b4d40cfae7f675a2c99a0e925157/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L163-L168):

> This attribute has effect only if the `text`
> attribute is set or unspecified, or if it is set to `auto` and the file
> is detected as text.
>
> Note that setting this attribute on paths which
> are in the index with CRLF line endings may make the paths to be
> considered dirty.
>
> Adding the path to the index again will normalize the line endings in the index.

---

To further clarify, with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), the documentation is updated:

See [commit 6a5678f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a5678f2576dba579e35c6d86b02584abee0ac37) (14 Feb 2022) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 66633f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66633f25c620bc622663a484c34e817b6cd97764), 23 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a5678f2576dba579e35c6d86b02584abee0ac37): clarify interaction between 'eol' and text=auto
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> The `eol` takes effect on text files only when the index has the contents in LF line endings.
> Paths with contents in CRLF line endings in the index may become dirty unless `text=auto`.

`gitattributes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a5678f2576dba579e35c6d86b02584abee0ac37/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L164-L169):

> This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the
> working directory.
>
> This attribute has effect only if the `text` attribute is set or unspecified, or if it is set to `auto`, the file is detected as text, **and it is stored with LF endings in the index**.
>
> Note that setting this attribute on paths which are in the index with CRLF line endings may make the paths to be considered dirty **unless `text=auto` is set**.
> Adding the path to the index again will normalize the line endings in the index.

---

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), in-tree `.gitattributes` update to match the way we recommend our users to mark a file as text.

See [commit 1f34e0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f34e0cd3d799acb5118b3276dde389821bffdd4) (03 Feb 2023) by [Philip Oakley (`PhilipOakley`)](https://github.com/PhilipOakley).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f7c208c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7c208cdf5b10df89a28320628e19e4c4a121629), 15 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`.gitattributes`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f34e0cd3d799acb5118b3276dde389821bffdd4): include `text` attribute for `eol` attributes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philip Oakley</sup>

> The standard advice for text file eol endings in the `.gitattributes` file was updated in [e28eae3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e28eae3184b26d3cf3293e69403babb5c575342c) (`gitattributes`: Document the unified , 2016-08-26, Git v2.10.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e28eae3184b26d3cf3293e69403babb5c575342c)) (gitattributes: Document the unified "auto" handling, 2016-08-26) with a recent clarification in [8c591db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c591dbfcef9b4d40cfae7f675a2c99a0e925157) ("`docs`: correct documentation about eol attribute", 2022-01-11, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8db2f665e1b25c2e88ddb00b402a4aa3b73a4cf4) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b80121027d1247a0754b3cc46897fee75c050b44)), with a follow up comment by the original author in [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20220216115239.uo2ie3flaqo3nf2d@tb-raspi4/T/#u), confirming the use of the eol attribute in conjunction with the text attribute.
>
> Update Git's `.gitattributes` file to reflect our own advice.

So instead of:

```
/Documentation/**/*.txt eol=lf
```

You now have:

```
/Documentation/**/*.txt text eol=lf
```