# Can't unmodify files in git

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-status, core.autocrlf

When I merged with another branch, a few of my files became modified automatically.
I tried to `checkout --` on the files, but `git status` still shows them as modified.

I then tried a custom shell function that normally fixes these kinds of problems for me:

```
cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`;
git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -d -f;
cd -; 
git rm -r --cached .
git reset --hard HEAD
```

The files still showed up as modified.

I tried  running these chunks of commands through different versions of:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

The files still show as modified.
I just want a clean `git status`...

Is there a command that is guaranteed to do this?

Comment: What is your OS? I had similar issues on Windows several years ago. I fixed it by setting `core.filemode` to `false`.

Comment: @Paul I'm on linux, but it's possible the files merged came from windows.  I've tried setting `core.filemode`, and re-running my commands.  They are still modified.

Comment: If you `git diff` your "modified" files what will you get?

Comment: Every line has changed, but they look exactly the same.  I assume its line ending related!?

Comment: Check for line-end adjustment in `.gitattributes` (via `eol=` conversions), or smudge and clean filters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076854/why-does-git-keep-messing-with-my-line-endings