# Bash scripts Git cloned in VSCode are automatically converted to DOS format

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, scripting, dos2unix

Platform: Windows 10
Editor: VSCode

Hi,

I am working on Windows using WSL and develop on VSCode. I notice that whenever I clone a project that contains Bash scripts into VSCode, these scripts are automatically converted to DOS format which means that I have to `dos2unix` these scripts before being able to use them.

For instance, if I clone [this repo](https://github.com/alexanderepstein/Bash-Snippets) full of Bash scripts in VSCode, and check any script using the command `dos2unix --info=u *`, it returns `0` for every Bash scripts which means they are not Unix-formatted.

However, if I simply download the repo directly from GitHub and check the info of the scripts, it shows that they are actually Unix-formatted.

Is there a way to avoid this automatic conversion and simply clone the repo as it is?

Comment: This depends on your git config setting for `autocrlf`,  try `git config --global core.autocrlf` and also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077666/1505939) for global .gitattributes file possibility

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem then it'd be helpful to write an answer

Answer (score 1):

I always start with `git config --global core.autocrlf false`: that takes care of any autmomagic conversion (which would be done by default on *all* files)
This is respected by VSCode.

Any eol conversion should be, as commented, done in a `.gitattributes` file if needed, [as I wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077666/6309): that way, even if `core.autocrlf` was left to true, it would not convert those files.